# Using Zip on set

Tags: python, set

When zip is applied on two lists:

`x = zip([1,2,3,4], [6,7,8,9])
print(list(x))`

yields
`[(1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 9)]`

But when I use sets in zip

`x = zip({1,2,3,4}, {6,7,8,9})
print(list(x))`

gives me
`[(1, 8), (2, 9), (3, 6), (4, 7)]`

Why?

And I also observed

`x = zip({1,2,3,4}, {6,7,8,9}, {12,13,14,15})
print(list(x))`

gives me 
`[(1, 8, 12), (2, 9, 13), (3, 6, 14), (4, 7, 15)]`

Answer (score 2):

Sets aren't ordered, so when zip iterates over them it may process its elements in a different order.